# Failure Sending Mail in C# SMTP server

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am writing web services for an application in which there is a registration function and upon registration i have to send an email through the server. i have already done this kind of work for another website with Parallel Plesk server. using the same code i'm trying to send email but getting this exception. I searched Google and some related answers here but all in vain. Help?

> "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'domainname.com'\r\n at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)\r\n at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)\r\n at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)\r\n at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)\r\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)\r\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)\r\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()\r\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)\r\n --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)\r\n at ActivityTracker.Controllers.ValuesController.parentRegistration(parent p) in c:\Users\Harris\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ActivityTracker\ActivityTracker\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 89"

Comment: Just read the error. _"The remote name could not be resolved: 'domainname.com"_. That domain name does not exist or cannot be resolved because you have a DNS issue.

Comment: already done that and searched for it but didn't find a solution

Comment: What did you search for? You're using the wrong SMTP host. Nobody else can fix that for you.

Comment: The solution is to make sure the firewall isn't blocking it, and make sure you are using the correct connection details. This is not a code problem.

Comment: i have tried 25 and 587 SMTP host. both gave same result.

Comment: should i enable SSL for this purpose?

Comment: You cannot resolve to the domain name you are trying to resolve to.  In other words, if you open command prompt and type ping, you cant resolve to the address domainname.com.  If you can, then its most likely a port issue, in which case, verify the ports using telnet.  If you cannot telnet then its confirmed there is a comms issue from the machine running your code to the destination relay server.  Once the comms issue is resolved, your code should run fine!

Comment: Its also worth checking you can ping and telnet to the actual IP address of domainname.com to see if its a DNS issue and not a comms issue (DNS being things like the "domainname.com" dns name is maybe not setup on your local network or your machine has a host file entry missing.  Comms issue being the machines in question cannot reach each other on the network - i.e. machine running code to the machine at the IP for domainname.com).

Comment: The message is *very* clear. You used the **wrong server address**. If the message is an exact copy, you tried to connect to a non-existent server called `domainname.com`. Did you copy the code from some sample and forgot to change the example's address?

Comment: @Panagiotis check the first revision of the question. That hostname cannot be resolved for me.

Comment: @CodeCaster it's almost the same case - the domain name was copied as-is, instead of using a valid mail server. Googling for this domain shows only the domain is registered, no IPs. Could it be that there is *no* mail server and the OP should look for a public service?

Comment: @Panagiotis it's possible that OP thinks that registering a domain automatically gives you a mail server, as it generally does when bundling it with shared hosting.

Comment: @Panagiotis i copied the code which is already running for another application's web services running on Parallels server. instead of that domain name i gave here the domain name for which i'm working. and that old piece of code is running absolutely fine

Comment: @Rob McCabe and one more thing i pinged the ip of the server and got the response from the server.

Comment: @HarrisNaeem the "old piece of code" has nothing with using the wrong server address. Instead of using a *domain name*, you should be using the *SMTP Server's name or address". `SomeDomainName.com` is *not* a valid server address. A valid address would be something like `smtp. somedomain.com`, or `someserver.somedomain.com`. Registering a domain doesn't mean you also get a mail server.

Comment: could it be a server problem on which i'm running the services?

Answer (score 0):

From the machine running your code:

- You CANNOT resolve *domainname.com*
- You CAN resolve to the IP address of *domainname.com*

This indicates that you are missing an internal DNS entry.

As your machine can talk to the IP but not using the DNS name - you can work around the issue by creating a Hostname entry for the domain name in question.

Here's how to modify your Hostname file:
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/modify-your-hosts-file

Once this entry is in place, you should now be able to ping to *domainname.com*. When that works - rerun your code.

Some useful DNS reading:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-how-dns-works-part-1/
http://social.dnsmadeeasy.com/blog/understanding-dns-forwarding/

NOTE: You've not confirmed if you can telnet to the port in question, so I am presuming this is ok - ruling out any firewall issues.

Answer (score -4):

Try to use GMail SMTP if it works with GMail SMTP then the problem exist with the domain you specified.

Comment: This is doesn't answer the question - if you type the address to GMail's server wrong,you'll get the *exact* same error.